# More animals per click with upgrades

Tags: javascript, html, increment

I want it so you can buy a upgrade for 1000 animals or so and your animals per click goes up from +1 to +2 per click. How can I accomplish this? http://jsfiddle.net/blosche/nHPMx/45/ I already have a store with things you can buy for animals that give you more animals per second, but I would like a new store where you can buys more animals when youu click the  + animals button.

```
    function addAnimal() {


        allCount += 1
    }
```

This is the function I have for adding +1 animal how can i make it so when you buy a thing it goes to +1 or

```
    function addAnimal() {


        allCount += 2
    }
```

With buying a upgrade?

Comment: My idea would be to save the number of bought Upgrades in a variable or localStorage or Cookie. And than you calculate with that number of bought upgrades the new allCount.

Comment: You might want to check out the aspect ratio of those animals first, they all look flat.

Comment: I see someone's been inspired by Cookie Clicker...

Comment: Relfic, I do not really get what you are saying, how would this increas animals per click when you buy a upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

So the animals per second is a function of the number of upgrades a person has? What counts as an upgrade? You probably want to call some update function that updates `animalsPerSecond` whenever you make an upgrade.

Something like:

```
function buySomeUpgrade() {
    // <Some upgrade here>
    updateStats(); // Update stats
};

function updateStats() {
    animalsPerSecond++;
};

function addAnimal() {
    allCount += animalsPerSecond;
};
```

For persistence on the client-side, you should probably set these values in a cookie. You can read more about how to do that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie).